# Recommended way to check if Dojo is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

In Dojo v1.8 and going forward, what is the recommended way to check if the Dojo library is already loaded (and if possible which version)?

For jQuery, I can use the jQuery namespace and the jQuery.jquery property. In Dojo, there's a legacy dojo namespace but if I understand correctly it will eventually be deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following suggestion from the [dojo mailing list](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/):

```
var isDojo = define && define.amd && define.amd.vendor && define.amd.vendor === "dojotoolkit.org";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2008/05/dojo_goodness_part_7_injecting.html), you can just say:

```
if (window.dojo !== undefined) {
    // dojo is loaded...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof(dojo) !== "undefined") {
   // dojo has been loaded
}
```

Comment: Any reference to support this? As I said in my question, this looks more like the legacy way.

Comment: How much new do you need ? Do you have some reference that its deprecated ? A quick search points to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ground/index.html) dated 18 Jan 2011 (DOJO 1.5)

Comment: v 1.8 and above, see my question.

Comment: Well, in the recent docs everything that starts with "dojo." is called "legacy", hence my assumption.